# how to reload DIV content without refreshing whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to only replace the DIV content with the content i get. After i make a get request to the server using ajax.

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/result/?age="+ ageData +"&occasion="+ 
    occasionData     +"&relationship="+ forData +"#",

    success: function () {

        $("#testDIV").load();
    }
});
```

"testDIV" is the id of the div with which i want to replace the content got from the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   $.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "ht.tp://127.0.0.1:8000/result/?age="+ ageData +"&occasion="+ 
occasionData     +"&relationship="+ forData +"#",

success: function (response) {

    $("#testDIV").html(response);
}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to fill the `<div>` with what is returned from your script:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/result/?age="+ ageData +"&occasion="+ 
    occasionData     +"&relationship="+ forData +"#",

    success: function (data) {

        $("#testDIV").html(data);
        //Puts response data inside <div id="testDIV"></div>
    }
});
```

Oh and please note the full stop within the `http://` prefix. Unless your using a new protocol not known to many of us - you'll want that gone.

Comment: I have tried your solution but i am getting 500 error code. Nothing is happening

Comment: Have you removed the period (`.`) from the address protocol?

Comment: Then I'm thinking theres a problem with the script at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/result/`. Are you using URL rewriting?

Comment: Then how exactly are you able to reach a script at that address? You need to make sure that address points the script that you want processing the request.

Comment: If i am using url directly from the browser the server is not showing error. But if i use ajax method . Then it will show error.

Comment: I found the problem with mu script..Now it is working. Thanks for help :)

Comment: @VaIbHaV-JaIn - if you notice a problem with your question (like the `ht.tp`) then please fix it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use the first argument of success handler which carries the content, and replace your div content with it using the `.html()` function:

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#testDIV").html(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But now the whole page is loading. But what i want is just to replace the old DIV contents with new DIV contents.

Answer (score 1):

here is the right success function :

```
success: function(htmlFromServer) {
     $("#testDIV").html(htmlFromServer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#testDIV").html(data);
}
```

Comment: @VaIbHaV-JaIn see the edited part. data is the response getting from AJAX request

Comment: I have tried every thing but getting same error at server side (500 error).

Answer (score 0):

```
 var url = "ht.tp://127.0.0.1:8000/result/?age="+ ageData +"&occasion="+ 
    occasionData+"&relationship="+ forData +"#";
    $('#testDIV').load(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get this done is by using the `.load` function

```
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/result/?age="+ ageData +"&occasion=" + occasionData     +"&relationship="+ forData +"#";
$("#testDIV").load(url);
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your help.. I solved the problem by loading contents from new View into the DIV elements.. Thanks guys for your advice and help...

Answer (score 0):

Response status codes beginning with the digit "5" indicate cases in which the server is aware that it has encountered an error or is otherwise incapable of performing the request. Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server should include an entity containing an explanation of the error situation, and indicate whether it is a temporary or permanent condition. Likewise, user agents should display any included entity to the user. These response codes are applicable to any request method.