# How to load new content to DIV without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web-deployment

I want to load new content from the server to the DIV without refreshing the whole page. 
I tried the following

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/result/?age="+ ageData +"&occasion="+ 
       occasionData     +"&relationship="+ forData +"#",
    success: function (response) {
        $("#testDIV").html(response);
    }
});
```

But the problem is the whole page is loading in `<DIV id="testDIV">`. I want to replace the old DIV with New DIV content returned from the server not with the whole page.

Comment: The error is outside the code you've posted. Do you use `<input type='submit' ...>` as a trigger for this code to be run?

Comment: Broken URL? Why the dot on `ht.tp`?!

Comment: @J0HN He is using ajax to grab "the whole page" as ajax is intended. He should try `.load` to grab a certain div from the retrieved page.

Comment: @JeffShaver ok, that won't change anything, the code he uses should not reload the page anyway. the error is somewhere outside.

Comment: @J0HN from what I understand: It isn't reloading. Simply, the div is getting the entire page. Instead he would like it to only contain the contents of a specific div on the page that is loaded. `But the problem is the whole page is loading in <DIV id="testDIV">`. Meaning, the div he is inserting data into is getting the entire fetched page.

Comment: Yes Jeff you are right. This page will contain the products information and as user will change the filter and click on the submit button the above mentioned function will called but it is loading the whole page. But i want only new products details.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15495967/472495) on the same day?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your same process sense you are interested in using AJAX directly and want to manage your done function (instead of success because [.done() will replace it](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)).  Here is how...

```
   .done(function(data) {
    ...
    }
```

Inside of that done function, you can filter the page content to what you want.  Simply request what you want to filter with jquery like this...

```
var $response = $(data);
var response_title = $response.filter(".title").html(); //I'm assuming you are trying to pull just the title (perhaps an < h1 > tag, in this little example, from the entire external page!
```

THEN!...

```
$("#testDIV").html(response_title);
```

With the done function, based on [jQuery's API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you can use this format...

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "some.php",
data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

So your final code may look something like this...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "ht.tp://127.0.0.1:8000/result/?age="+ ageData +"&occasion="+  occasionData     +"&relationship="+ forData +"#"})
    .done(function(response) {
    var $response = $(response);
    var response_title = $response.filter(".title").html(); 
    $("#testDIV").html(response_title);
    });
```

Comment: The use of the filter to get what you need is the best idea, but you should stop using success, it is deprecated, use done instead: var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
     .done(function() { alert("success"); });

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('.classloader.').on('click', function(e){

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/result/?age="+ ageData +"&occasion="+ 
   occasionData +"&relationship="+ forData +"#",
            beforeSend:  function() {
                $("#testDIV").hide();
                $('div#loading').show();
            },
            success: function(html){
                $("#testDIV").html($(html).filter("#mainContent").html()).show();
                $('div#loading').hide();
            }
        });     
        return false;
    });
})
```

Comment: I tried your solution but DIV content are just hiding that's it nothing else happening...Please help me out...

Comment: I've modified it. After loading the div, you then have to unhide it using `.show()`.

Comment: what do you mean by 'div#loading' ???

Comment: No, `$("#testDIV").html($(html).filter("#mainContent").html()).show();`. I've updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer by [blackhawk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/957186/blachawk). It uses the existing code with slight modification.

I would just condense it to a one line change like this:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/result/?age="+ ageData +"&occasion="+ 
     occasionData+"&relationship="+ forData +"#",
     success: function (response) {
         $("testDIV").html($(data).filter(".title").html());
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you are displaying is actually correct.
The problem comes from what your server is providing.

What you are doing here is GETing a **whole page** via an AJAX call, and replacing the content of **One div** with that whole page.

Your server should not render the whole page for that call, but only the content of the div you wish to replace. If you are using framework like rails or symfony, they often provide an easy way to detect if the query is a normal GET request, or an AJAX call.

Basically you have 4 strategies at your disposal :

1. Make the requests to a specific endpoint that is used only for the ajax call and that returns the content of the div you wish to replace. And not the whole page.
2. Make the request to the same page, and detect if the request is a normal HTTP request or an AJAX call. Based on that, return the whole page or just the content of the div. You'll probably have to look for the helpers in your framework / toolbox documentation.
3. Make the AJAX request but ask for a JSON object. Transform your JSON in HTML on the client side to replace the content of the div. This is the "my app is just an API" approach. This is my personal favorite as this JSON endpoint can be used for other purposes (eg: a mobile app) since it carries only content, and not presentation. This also tends to be the fastest way in terms of performance since a significant part of the computation is done on the client side. On the con side, this requires you to write more JS.
4. Always render the whole page, and filter only what you need on the client side. This is balchawk approach. Benefit is that you don't have to modify your server, but you will waste processing time and bandwidth by returning a whole page, when only a subset is necessary.

Comment: I am using Django for my webAPP. So u r saying that i should have another view to handle these type of requests. Which will return only the required text and then replace it with the old one

Comment: Exactly, depending on the complexity, you will want to use the same action and route, and just call a different view, or you will have to create a new action and route. That's up to you.